# Create a collection class that contains a list

Tags: java

I have a class that contains information:

```
class Artists {
    int id;
    String description;
    int year;

    void insert(int i, String d, int y) {
        id = i;
        description = d;
        year = y;
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println(id + description + year);
    }
}

public class ArtistsRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Artists a1 = new Artists();
        Artists a2 = new Artists();
        Artists a3 = new Artists();

        a1.insert(23, "An", 2015);
        a2.insert(13, "Mon", 2089);
        a3.insert(11, "Gla", 2013);

        a1.display();
        a1.display();
        a3.display();
    }
}
```

**I want to make another java class with a collection class of the list of artists. How would I retrieve info from the artists class , make that into a list in my new java class?**

I think I have to:

1. declare a static collection field in my class with the main method
2. create a new artist, add it to that collection

Is this correct? How would I do this?
(still very new to Java)

Comment: Please [edit] the post and format the code properly.

Comment: Your Artists class seems like it should be Artist -- it only holds a single artist ...

Comment: Create an ArrayList and add a1,a2,a3 to that list. And, yeah.. static field is fine.

Comment: Artists should be Artist since each Artist object represent a single artist.  You can just use ArrayList to store your Artist objects unless the assignment specific asks you to write your own collection class.

Comment: Your `#insert` method could simply be in the constructor for `Artists`. I'd also rename `Artists` to `Artist`, as it currently seems to represent a single `Artist` overall. From there, you could simply make a `List<Artist>` of the various artists of interest.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've already asked this question earlier this day.

Comment: @Rogue there is 3 artists the a1,a2 and a3. Would I make the list in the main class or the new class?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a List, and put your Artist instances into it.

```
List<Artists> myArtists = new ArrayList<>();
myArtists.add(a1);
myArtists.add(a2);
myArtists.add(a3);
```

Since your requirement is to create a "static" list (probably for an assignment because you'd never want to do this in real life), declare the list at the class level and populate it (`add` statements) in `main`.

You can add any (reasonable) number of artists to this list using the `add` method as you create new artists instances.

---

Beyond that, you've got some basic issues with the design of your classes. While they *work*, they're not necessarily *correct*.

Your "Artists" class contains information for only a single artist, so the class should be called Artist (singular.) Further, the `insert` method is populating that artist, and should be a constructor.

```
public class Artist {
  private int id;
  private String description;
  private int year;

  public Artist(int id, String description, int year) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.year = year;
  }

  public void display() {
    System.out.println(id + description + year);
  }
}
```

Note your display method is a bit weird -- there's no spaces between those variable values.

You'd now create a new artist like this:

```
Artist a1 = new Artist(1, "Bob", 2010);
```

This makes the "populate the list" exercise even easier, since you can do it in one line:

```
List<Artist> myArtists = new ArrayList<>();
myArtists.add(new Artist(1, "Bob", 2010));
```

Also, unless your assignment specifically asks for a "runner" class, you could just stick the main method right on the Artist class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` method could be reduced to this:

```
record Artist ( int id , String description , Year year ) {}
List < Artist > artists = 
    List.of
    (
        new Artist ( 23, "An", Year.of( 2015 ) ) ,
        new Artist ( … ) ,
        new Artist ( … ) 
    )
;
System.out.println( artists ) ;
```

A [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395?source=:so:tw:or:awr:odv:::) is a brief way to define a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. A record can be defined locally, within a method.

[`java.time.Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) is a class for representing a year.

Comment: Keep in mind that `record` can only be used java 14+.
Hopefully for learning a modern version is used but for legacy issues/... i would use a simple classy collection without the record

Comment: @LenglBoy (a) Actually, Java 16+ for `record`. (b) Java 17 is the latest long-term support version. So there is no need to point out versions when the Question has no specific constraint. Otherwise all Answers here would be written for Java 1.0.

Comment: Actually you can use `record` since Java 14 but the final/current implementation is fixed since 16. Just wanted to mention it since such basic questions might need additional information.

Comment: @LenglBoy I would *not* suggest preview features to beginners. I believe Java-related Answers should by default be written using the latest long-term support version of Java, using only final features (no previews). Exceptions include: (a) Question stating an earlier version as a constraint, (b) Answers purposely using a specific feature of particular interest, final or preview, that exists in a later interim release of Java. Perhaps this issue would be a good subject for a page on https://meta.stackexchange.com/.